# Import dates from list into calendar app

Tags: 2013, list, calendar, app

I'm trying to show the birthdays from a list in my calendar. I completed the following steps so far:

- Created new app Contacts "Friends"
- Filled it with some sample data: 
  [image: friends sample data]
- Created new app Calendar "MyCalendar"
- In MyCalendar
  -> List Settings
  -> Create Column
  -> Lookup
  -> Get information from: Friends
  -> In this column: Birthday
  -> Add a column to show each of these additional fields: Last name, First name (in order to see whose birthday it is)

Despite the steps explained above, my calendar remains empty.

1. How to show the birthdays from the list in MyCalendar?
2. How to make them a repeating event?
3. Is it possible, to show them in an additional overlay? So I could have multiple overlays (e.g. birthday, meetings, etc.) in one calendar app?

**Update**:

4. How to show the upcoming birthday in an additional list at the start page?
   I know how to make lists, I'm just not sure about how to import there data (birthdays) from another list (friends) automatically.

I really appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1):

Creating a lookup column will not add data from the lookup list.

While creating events in the calendar list (app) you can pick the friends value from the lookup list.

To automate this process you can

1. Create a workflow that runs every day - Not recommended
2. Create a timer job that runs every day

You can add another calendar for keeping track of meetings. Then you can add this meeting calendar as an overlay to your Birthday calendar.

Comment: I will add new people rarely, maybe once a month. Having a timer running would consume unnecessary resources. Isn't there a more elegant solution? Would it be more convenient, to have the upcoming birthday shown in an additional list and the start page?